# Use Express Route in If?

Tags: node.js, express

Is it possible to use Express to render a user page, if the user is in an array? Something like

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var users = ["Community", "bjskistad", "sindresorhus"]

app.get(null, function(req, res){
    for(var i in array){
        if(i in array){
            app.get("/"+i, function(req, res){
                res.send(//whatever);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Or can Express only display static pages?

Comment: null will not match any path, so your logic is flawed. see my answer for some direction

Comment: @kennasoft null was just an example! Your answer worked quite nicely, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid approach is

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var users = ["Community", "bjskistad", "sindresorhus"]

app.get("/:user", function(req, res){ //the username is a path parameter
    var curentUser = req.params.user; //retrieve the username
    if(users.indexOf(currentUser)>-1){ //check if user is in array
        res.send(/*whatever*/);       //send the expected page
        //or 
        //res.redirect(/*whatever else*/); //or redirect to another url
    } else {
        res.send(/*403 page*/);
    }
}
```